# I use select2 formatSelection ,but a style error has occured

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

```
var list = e.data.goods_list;

$.each(list, function(k, v) {
    var str = '';
    str = str + '<optgroup label="'+v[0].store_name+'">';
    $.each(v, function(kk, vv) {
        str = str + '<option value="'+vv.goods_id+'">'+vv.goods_name+'</option>';
    });
    str = str + '</optgroup>';
    $('#goodsSelect2').append(str);
});

$('#goodsSelect2').select2({formatSelection:test});
console.log(@goodsIds);

var goodsIdsStr = "@goodsIds";
if(goodsIdsStr !=null && goodsIdsStr != "" && goodsIdsStr != undefined){
    var arr = goodsIdsStr.split(",");
    console.log(arr);
    $("#goodsSelect2").val(arr).trigger('change');
}
```

Above is part of my code. When I use `$('#goodsSelect2').select2();`, all is ok 
[image]

However when I use `$('#goodsSelect2').select2({formatSelection:test})`, the function "test" is useful but the style is wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

formatSelection must return e.text, or it render wrong